# How to display User from Access Log in Views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

The [statistics module documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) says that user name is logged in the Access Log: "This access log is used to store data about every page accessed, such as the remote host's IP address, where they came from (referrer), what node they've viewed, **and their user name**. "

I have enabled statistics Acces Log and created a view which shows Access Log. Available fields are:

[image]

I can't find any field related to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a relationship to Users to be able to display user fields in the view.

1. Click on Add next to Relationships.
2. Check "Access log: User" then click Apply.
3. Click Add next to Fields then you should see the User fields including username.